# I have some issues with RewriteCond with Apache and subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess, plesk, amazon-lightsail

I changed from cPanel to Plesk in Lightsail AWS and I have an odd issue.

When I had cPanel instance I could enter links like this:
https://cmc.injectxgames.io/r89x681k78b/testing
Now, in Plesk, I have an error 404, but I set a domain to that same folder and is working fine:
https://www.sniperelite.xyz/r89x681k78b/testing

Those 2 links are pointing to the same folder on server, the only difference that I see is the subdomain.

This is the .htaccess file:

```
## Begin - SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - SEF Section.

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 250
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 128M
   php_value post_max_size 64M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 250
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 128M
   php_value post_max_size 64M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Configure el paquete “ea-php74” como el lenguaje de programación predeterminado “PHP”.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

I have all week fighting with this, what could be the issue?

Comment: "to that same folder" - Are you suggesting `/r89x681k78b/testing` is a physical "folder"? Or is this really just a URL-path that should be routed through your front-controller (`index.php`)? As an experiment, try adding `RewriteRule ^r89 index.php [L]` at the top of the `.htaccess` file (and perhaps commenting out the later rule).

Comment: No, is not, that is a test token that I created for this question. That are params that can be passed to the API. "r89x681k78b" is the public token assigned to use the API (this is just temporal) and "testing" is the method to invoke (here can be several actions depending what is requested). Therefor, that are not folders. The issue is that only fails when I invoke by a subdomain, that is odd.